# Checking whether CRS is geographic coordinate system or projected coordinate system using R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, proj, sp, rgdal

I am writing a generic script that would calculate areas covered by different classes in a categorical raster in R.
I would like to provide two functions; one for use when the CRS of the raster is geographic (long, lat), and one to use when the CRS is projected.

Is there a way I can check that?

I imagine there is a property of the CRS string I'd check in an `if()` statement for that

Comment: Pyproj has a function proj.crs.is_geographic for that purpose, perhaps you can find something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `raster` package has a function `isLonLat` for this purpose.
Analogous for vector data, there is the `st_is_longlat` function from `sf`.